# Multiple notification handling

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm having trouble in figuring out the **Intent**, **PendingIntent** **Filters** and **Flags** for notifications.

Notification are working and are getting generated as they should, but the problem is only the last notification created keeps the **Bundle Data**.

I want all notification to keep the **Bundle Data** of each notification in it until a user click on them.

Consider an application for a moment when different user send you a message a new notification gets created and when you click on any notification the app launches and takes you to some specific Activity. I want the same thing but when there are more than one notification the last notification keeps the **Data** where as previous notification loose their **Bundle Data** and **Intent**.

There is another thing which **Filters** to use to restrict the app from launching a new instance of **MainActivity** everytime a notification is clicked at.

The **Notification_ID** are different for each notification.

```
public class AlarmSchedulingService extends IntentService {
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public AlarmSchedulingService() {
    super("SchedulingService");
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        sendNotification(extras.getInt(KEY_EXTRAS_NOTIFICATION_ID));
}

public void sendNotification(int NOTIFICATION_ID) {
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(keyName, extraData); 
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // use the right class it should be called from the where alarms are set
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(titleString)
            .setStyle(
                    new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                            .bigText(messageString))
            .setDefaults(
                Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND
                | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)

            .setContentText(messageString);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
     }
 }
```

Comment: You can compare ids in your Broadcast receiver by sending them in extras of intent.

Comment: yes i have checked it already all of them have the same Notification_ID where as i'm assigning each one a unique Notification_ID. All of them have the last assigned Notification_ID, their own Notification_ID are overwritten by the recent most

Comment: now Its clear that your id is overwriting please debug and check.

Comment: Please post where exactly you are generating unique notification id. There is no way android notification manager overwrites notification Id with latest one. Please recheck your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is Showing that :

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

You are giving request code 0 to all notifications.
0 should be replaced by each unique number, otherwise, each new notification will override the old one.

Comment: This is not the notification ID. This is the `requestCode` parameter for the `PendingIntent`. Your suggestion is correct: this needs to be unique, but the explanation is wrong.